# Laravel Session cannot Increase the variable value

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, session-variables

I need to increase a variable value through session every time i click on a button. But session always returns me the value to 1. Seems like it is forgetting the original value. If i use dd() method before retrieving the value it will be showing the value to be null. But after pushing the value to the session when i use dd() method then it will show the value is in the session.It seems like it is forgetting the value.Do i need to put web middlewware on laravel 5.3? or any other configurations to make it work? Please help me i tried to fix it in every possible way and i am stucked for about three days now. Thank you very much.Following is my code

my class

```
class Cart
{
public $totalQuantity;


public function __construct($oldVal)
{
    if ($oldVal) {

        $this->totalQuantity = $oldVal->totalQuantity;
    }

}

public function add()
{
    $this->totalQuantity=$this->totalQuantity+1;

}
```

}

my controller

```
public function getAddToCart(Request $request){

    $oldValue=0;
    // i get the value to null though i click button many times
    dd($request->session()->get('val'));

    if ($request->session()->has('val')) {
        $oldValue = $request->session()->get('val');
    }

    $cart = new Cart($oldValue);
    $cart->add();
    session(['val' => $cart]);
    // Here it shows the value.
    dd($request->session()->get('val'));

 }
```

My route

```
Route::get('/productInfo/{id}/addToCart',['uses'=>'searchController@getAddToCart','as'=>'product.addToCart'] );
```

[image: 2nd dd methods snip]

please help me thanks a lot

Comment: What does this give you -> `dd($request->session()->has('val'));` ?

Comment: it returns me false

Comment: Try this. Session::put('key', 'val') & Session::get('key')

Comment: Still the same it returns me false or null in the first dd() and if i use the 2nd dd() then it wil show the value as 1

Comment: do i need some prior configurations to be done. i am using file session type

Comment: Are you tried to use this code with `web` middleware?

Comment: no i did not exactly know how to do it cause i am a beginer. i am using laravel 5.3

Comment: @hEShaN Please understand that Laravel 5.3 by default uses the **web** middleware in all its routes written in `routes/web.php` .

Comment: so why this simple chunck of code is not working for me?

Comment: @hEShaN What does `dd($request->session()->has('val'));` give you after this line -> `session(['val' => $cart]);` and after the second time you click the button? Also, please tag me next time you comment or I won't get a notification.

Comment: @prateekkathal on that dd() it always returns me the totalQuantity as 1. though its the first time or any time. i had attached that image

Comment: @prateekkathal i forgot to tag you. just saw your comment's latter part